# Determine Neo4j database version

Tags: java, neo4j, neo4j-java-api

The Neo4j Java API automatically updates outdated databases to the current version when I call

`new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase(File storeDir)`

I would like to check what version the database is before doing that. Is there a way to do that with the Java API? Or alternatively: Where is the database version stored so I can read it out manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Release version**

I dug into the Neo4j API source and found an answer. Neo4j reads out the previous version from the `debug.log` file in the `logs` directory. Whenever the database is started the version is printed into the log file as `Kernel version: (this is where you'll find the version)`. For instance it could look like this:

```
2017-11-21 06:21:43.460+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] Kernel version: 3.3.0,5b700972242a5ec3e0140261120f2845fb3520ad
```

You could read out the debug.log the Neo4j way:

```
import java.io.File;

import org.neo4j.io.fs.DefaultFileSystemAbstraction;
import org.neo4j.io.fs.FileSystemAbstraction;
import org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.log.LogTailScanner;
import org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.log.PhysicalLogFile;
import org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.log.PhysicalLogFiles;
import org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.log.ReadableClosablePositionAwareChannel;
import org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.log.entry.LogEntryReader;
import org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.log.entry.LogEntryVersion;
import org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.log.entry.VersionAwareLogEntryReader;

public class Neo4jVersionChecker {

    //Note that this method needs the store directory NOT the debug.log file
    public static String getNeo4jVersion(File storeDir) {   
        FileSystemAbstraction fileSystem = new DefaultFileSystemAbstraction();
        final PhysicalLogFiles logFiles = new PhysicalLogFiles( storeDir, PhysicalLogFile.DEFAULT_NAME, fileSystem );
        final LogEntryReader<ReadableClosablePositionAwareChannel> logEntryReader = new VersionAwareLogEntryReader<>();
        LogTailScanner tailScanner = new LogTailScanner( logFiles, fileSystem, logEntryReader );

        LogEntryVersion version = tailScanner.getTailInformation().latestLogEntryVersion;

        if(version!=null) {
                return version.toString();
        } else {
                return null;
        }
    }

}
```

The above method returns `V3_0_10` for a `debug.log` whose latest `Kernel version` entry is the one above.

Unfortunately the Neo4j way is not very precise. As you can see the `Kernel version` from the `debug.log` starts with `3.3.0` but the Neo method says it is `V3_0_10`. I'm assuming this has something to do with the way Neo handles versions internally.

But since we now know how Neo4j gets the version, we can do the same thing in a more exact way:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

import org.apache.commons.io.input.ReversedLinesFileReader;

public class VersionChecker {

    public static String getVersion(File storeDir) {
        File debugLog = new File(storeDir, "logs" + File.separator + "debug.log");
        if(debugLog.exists()) {
            try {
                //The ReversedLinesFileReader reads the last line of a file first and so on
                ReversedLinesFileReader reader = new ReversedLinesFileReader(debugLog, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                //Read last line
                String line = reader.readLine();
                while(line!=null) {
                    //Line can't be null at this point

                    if(line.contains("Kernel version: ")) {
                        //This line contains the version
                        line = line.substring(line.indexOf("Kernel version: ")).substring(16);  //get rid of everything except the version
                        line = line.split(",")[0];  //get rid of the second part of the Kernel version that we don't want
                        return line;
                    }

                    //Next line
                    line = reader.readLine();
                }
                reader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

The method above will return `3.3.0`.

**Store version**

Of course both of these methods only work if there is a debug.log file. Not all previous Neo4j versions have them. As long as the store directory contains the `neostore` file you can read out the `store version` which is not as nice as reading out the release version but at least it is something. So here's how that works:

There is a Neo4j class called `StoreVersionCheck` which contains a very handy method called `getVersion(File neostoreFile)`. Unfortunately we need an instance of something called a `PageCache` to initialize an instance of `StoreVersionCheck`. We can make a `PageCache`, so that is what we'll do.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.function.Consumer;

import org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseSettings;
import org.neo4j.io.fs.DefaultFileSystemAbstraction;
import org.neo4j.io.fs.FileSystemAbstraction;
import org.neo4j.io.pagecache.PageCache;
import org.neo4j.kernel.configuration.Config;
import org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory;
import org.neo4j.kernel.impl.pagecache.ConfiguringPageCacheFactory;
import org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storemigration.StoreVersionCheck;
import org.neo4j.kernel.impl.util.Neo4jJobScheduler;
import org.neo4j.kernel.monitoring.Monitors;
import org.neo4j.kernel.monitoring.tracing.Tracers;
import org.neo4j.logging.Log;
import org.neo4j.logging.Logger;
import org.neo4j.scheduler.JobScheduler;

public class StoreVersionChecker {

    public static String getStoreVersion(File storeDir) {
        File storeFile = new File(storeDir, "neostore");
        if(!storeFile.exists()) {
            return null;
        }
        StoreVersionCheck check = new StoreVersionCheck(buildPageCache());
        try {
            Optional<String> version = check.getVersion(storeFile);
            if(version.isPresent()) {
                return version.get();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    private static PageCache buildPageCache() {
        FileSystemAbstraction fileSystem = new DefaultFileSystemAbstraction();
        Config config = Config.defaults();
        Log pageCacheLog = new DummyLog();
        String desiredImplementationName = config.get( GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.Configuration.tracer );
        Monitors monitors = new Monitors();
        JobScheduler jobScheduler = new Neo4jJobScheduler();
        Tracers tracers = new Tracers( desiredImplementationName, new DummyLog(), monitors, jobScheduler );
        ConfiguringPageCacheFactory pageCacheFactory = new ConfiguringPageCacheFactory(fileSystem, config, tracers.pageCacheTracer, tracers.pageCursorTracerSupplier, pageCacheLog );
        PageCache pageCache = pageCacheFactory.getOrCreatePageCache();

        if ( config.get( GraphDatabaseSettings.dump_configuration ) )
        {
            pageCacheFactory.dumpConfiguration();
        }
        return pageCache;
    }

    //We need this so we can give the Tracers a Log
    private static class DummyLog implements Log {

        @Override
        public boolean isDebugEnabled() {return false;}

        @Override
        public Logger debugLogger() {return null;}

        @Override
        public void debug(String message) {}

        @Override
        public void debug(String message, Throwable throwable) {}

        @Override
        public void debug(String format, Object... arguments) {}

        @Override
        public Logger infoLogger() {return null;}

        @Override
        public void info(String message) {}

        @Override
        public void info(String message, Throwable throwable) {}

        @Override
        public void info(String format, Object... arguments) {}

        @Override
        public Logger warnLogger() {return null;}

        @Override
        public void warn(String message) {}

        @Override
        public void warn(String message, Throwable throwable) {}

        @Override
        public void warn(String format, Object... arguments) {}

        @Override
        public Logger errorLogger() {return null;}

        @Override
        public void error(String message) {}

        @Override
        public void error(String message, Throwable throwable) {}

        @Override
        public void error(String format, Object... arguments) {}

        @Override
        public void bulk(Consumer<Log> consumer) {}

    }

}
```