# How to check if a Neo4j database existis at a given location

Tags: java, neo4j, neo4j-java-api

Calling

```
new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase(File storeDir);
```

in the Neo4j Java API not only opens a database at a given location but also creates one if it doesn't already exist.

I would like to check if a Neo4j database exists in a given directory without creating one if it doesn't. How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now do this by checking if there is a `neostore` file in the store directory and by trying to get it's version.

See how you can get the store version here: [Determine Neo4j database version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47378638/determine-neo4j-database-version/47422082#47422082)